# Sign Blackberry 10 applications with different certificates

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm building a process to sign Blackberry applications with different certificates.

The idea is that the user could upload their author.p12, barsigner.cks and barsigner.db, as well as their password, and the server would use those certs to sign a .bar file.

The problem is that when I'm running blackberry-signer, I cannot specify the paths of those files, that tool is trying to get them from "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Research In Motion".

Is there a way to specify the path to those files when signing with blackberry-signer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried a similar thing and found we couldn't specify paths to the relevant signing files - the command line options didn't seem to work. We worked around this by writing a script which would copy the signing files the the Research in Motion folder for the duration of the signing process

Comment: Thanks, I'll do something similar, since there's no other apparent way :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output from the command-line the following option sounds like it should work `-keystore <file>             - file containing developer certificate`